# What does the option -nr mean in sed?

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying out the sed command and I came across this strange option **"-nr"**, I am using the sed command with this alias:

```bash
alias 20='printf "%03d\n" {1..20}'
```

The two commands have the same output, but I'm not sure if they're the same, **the manual doesn't contain this option**.

```bash
20 | sed -nr '5,$p'
```

```bash
20 | sed -n '5,$p'
```

Both return:

```
005
006
007
008
009
010
011
012
013
014
015
016
017
018
019
020
```

Comment: `the manual doesn't contain this option` That's odd, what manual are you reading?

Comment: @KamilCuk I am running the zsh shell on macOS and am looking at ```man sed```

Comment: `-nr` (with only one minus) is equivalent of `-n -r`. See `man sed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man sed`:

-E Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's)

-r Same as -E for compatibility with GNU sed.

I'm using gsed in MacOS and get the output. Which is correct!

Comment: Does it have a specific use other than getting the same output?

Comment: In this case you are not using Regular Expresions so the `-r` flag isn't necessary.